# Failed statements in Unlogged batch

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I am using **Cassandra Java driver**.
I have a use case in which I do 'unlogged batch insert data into various Cassandra tables having different partition key.

```
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
batch.add (query1, query2, .....)
session.executeAsync(batch);
```

Consider I have 20 queries in my batch statement, 15 queries are executed well and 5 queries failed.
**How can I know which queries failed and which got executed.**
I am using `executeAsync` because of performance perspective.